# New Design Launched

Tags: discussion, design

Hi guys,

As you can see, the new design launched. Grats, and thank you for forming such a wonderful gaming community.

> #### [» Click here to post feedback about any css or rendering issues.](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=bug+design)
>
> <sub>That is, please [start a new question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=bug+design) about it, instead of replying to this post.</sub>

If you catch me in chatroom, feel free to @-reply me too.

Comment: Would you like people to tag the question with something specific for you to find it easier?

Comment: @Juan I guess `design` will do.

Comment: yes just design is fine.

Comment: Are announcements truly legal questions, how does a "question" like this follow the guidelines set forth in the meta FAQ?  If such announcements are legal then why isn't it spelled out in the FAQ?

Answer (score 10):

I like everything alot (coin badges ftw) but is it just me or is the question title font little too pixelation and blocky?

Comment: I love the style overall, but this question title font isn't readable enough.

Comment: I agree. The design overall is very pleasant in its own pixelated way, but the question title is an exception. It should be easier on the eyes.

Comment: That was the first thing I noticed also.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe a new design? I really appreciate the attempt of re-vamping it, but the user interface is not intuitive / evident. Kind of takes a while to know what's going on. It's a really great idea, I just think it needs a little more work on the execution.

Thanks =)

Comment: Sorry, we cannot rearrange items or changr the styling too much, this site is just one of many. Check the StackExchange(tm) MultiCollider SuperDropdown(tm) at the top left of each page for more information.

Answer (score 5):

The question and answer scores are really small relative to Stack Overflow, as well as the title text (e.g. "New Design Launched" here), and titles on lists of questions aren't anywhere near as bold.

[image: SO vs Gaming]

Comment: I will up the font size soon.

Answer (score 4):

Might I go against the flow, by suggesting the the new style isn't that great? It's certainly a victory for style over substance.

It's OK, but I agree that the question and title fonts (Tagged/Asked/Viewed/Latest Activity/etc) are poor. The Space Invader-scarred tabs are amusing the first time you see them, I guess.

I get the whole retro thing, but there is a reason why graphics have advanced - we all know that graphics should always come second to game-play, but after the first visit, the novel impact is lost and we are all squinting.

It just seems like we are trying to be twee and retro-cool at the expense of usability. Once the initial impact is over, we are simple left with a standard stackexchange site with awkward fonts.

It's not going to put me (or anyone else, I suspect) off the site, but since you asked the question....

Answer (score 3):

I was pretty pleased with Gaming until I saw Cooking - the overall coherence of the design there really makes Gaming look a little less polished to me.

I feel the top banner is just so busy that it doesn't have the impact I'd like, and the individual questions (front page view) on Gaming don't have any elements that give me a "gaming" feel.

Maybe part of it is that "Food & Cooking" is a title that allows a little more design creativity - it's hard to do a lot when you only have the 6 characters of "Gaming" to work with.

Perhaps when an elevator pitch/tagline is worked out for Gaming that can be incorporated in a meaningful way and we can end up with something that feels more coherent?

Comment: I see the designs on all SE sites as ever evolving. I'll revisit each site and brainstorm with you guys when time allows. Meanwhile, feel free to post your ideas in details.

Answer (score 1):

I'm definitely going to create new meta-questions for bugs or issues, but I wanted to use this question to thank you for your work. Also, while I don't like 100% of everything, I just wanted to mention a few things which I find absolutely awesome:

1. The logo and title are both excellent; their pixelated design, their gradient fill, their glow effect... they even look great in black and white here on meta.
2. The coins for badges are brilliant, pure and simple.
3. The 404 page is awesome :)